# 1 to 1..0 relationship in an embedded form with doctrine

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

One user may have just 1 item or none. (1-1..0 relationship)

I'm trying to accomplish that in symfony2 with doctrine.

I've accomplished an 1 to 1 relationship, it's fairly simple. But how can I specify to doctrine that when I want to **create** an user, the item can be null? **(and not to insert a new row and just leave id_item null)**

This is what I have:

```
// User Class
     /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Items", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_item", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * 
     * @var SOA\AXBundle\Entity\Items $userItem
     * @Assert\Type(type="SOA\AXBundle\Entity\Items")
     */ 
    protected $userItem;
```

And of course, I created ItemsTypeForm class, and added the type in my userstypeform class:

```
// UsersTypeForm Class
     ->add('userItem', new \SOA\AXBundle\Form\ItemsTypeForm())
```

When I add a new user, everything goes fine. The user is inserted as well as the item. But when I try to **add** an user where it has no item (**user item fields are blank**), I get the following error:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null`

**It is trying to insert the item, with null values.**

While I can live with an 1 to 1 relationship, I would like to learn how to make an 1 to 1..0 relationship.

**edited with the real problem.** edits are bold.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation of the Assert is causing a problem. You must set that the null value is valid in the Assert.

Comment: I believe assert has nothing to do with it, I don't see any 'valid null value' other than the nullable value in the joincolumn annotation. And I edited my question, my problem now is when I try to create a new user without an item, it tries to insert a new item with blank values.

Comment: Do you have the userItem.name in the twig of the form?

Comment: Yes. do I have to de-attach it or something like that?