# There is a form which associated with two entities. I need to make one entity optional - symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an employee registration form as below,

```
namespace Hrm\EmployeeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Hrm\UserBundle\Form\User\UserForm;

class EmpForm extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{   
    $builder->add('id','hidden');
    $builder->add('firs_name', 'text');
    $builder->add('middle_name', 'text');
    $builder->add('last_name', 'text');     
    $builder->add('user', new UserForm(), array('required' => false));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'EmpForm';
}

}
```

also I have a user login form as below,

```
namespace Hrm\UserBundle\Form\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class UserForm extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
  {   
    $builder->add("id","hidden",array("required"=>false));
    $builder->add("userName","text",array("label"=>"Username"));
    $builder->add("password","password",array("label"=>"Password"));
    $builder->add("confirmPassword","password",array("property_path" => 
                   false,"label"=>"Confirm Password"));
    $builder->add("email","email",array("label"=>"Email"));
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'user';
  }
}
```

Employee YML file would be as follow,

```
Hrm\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee:
type: entity
table: employee
fields:
  id:
    type: integer
    id: true
    generator:
      strategy: AUTO
  firs_name:
    type: string
    length: '255'
    default: null
  middle_name:
    type: string
    length: '255'
    default: null
  last_name:
    type: string
    length: '255'
    default: null  
  oneToOne:
    User:
      targetEntity: Hrm\UserBundle\Entity\User
      cascade: ["remove", "persist"]
      joinColumn:
        name: login_id        
        referencedColumnName: id        
        nullable: true                   
 lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Employee Controller is like this,

```
public function addEmployeeAction(Request $request) {

    $employee = new Employee();

    $user = new User();
    $employee->setUser($user);

    $form = $this->createForm(new EmpForm(), $employee);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($employee);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('HrmEmployeeBundle_homepage'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('HrmEmployeeBundle:Pages:add.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(), 'status' => 'addEmployee',
            ));
}
```

So what I need to do is that following options should be available,

1. Fill employee registration details and create a login (this is already done)
2. Fill only employee registration details and do not need to create a login for that.

So second option not working for me and it says Column 'username' cannot be null
How can I get rid of this issue ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, in your addEmployeeAction, don't add a user on the new employee, remove these lines:

```
$user = new User();
$employee->setUser($user);
```

Currently, the $employee is saved with an empty user, who don't have username, so MySQL is unhappy !
By removing these lines, the user will be created only if its form is filled !

Comment: I tried it as you said above. But still getting following error.       Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to   Hrm\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee::setUser() must be an instance of Hrm\UserBundle\Entity\User, array given, called in                                I found a similar question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041671/symfony2-1-to-1-0-relationship-in-an-embedded-form-with-doctrine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a SQL field optionnal, add the nullable option true:

```
oneToOne:
    User:
      targetEntity: Sys\UserBundle\Entity\User
      cascade: ["persist"]
      joinColumn:
        name: login_id
        referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: true
```

But in your case, its seems that you registered a user with no username, which is not logical... Maybe the username field is not working fine, please give us more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sybio. I edited the question again. Please help me.Thanks again.